# at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, heroku, deployment

Hoping to get some help deploying my application. I have created an app with Typescript/React/Express/Mongodb and I've been trying to deploy it on Heroku, however I'm stuck on these errors and I'm not sure how to proceed. I thought it was a issue with my start script, so I've changed it a few times - same errors. I think maybe this is a typescript error but I'm not so sure. Thanks for any help!

Error:

```
2021-12-05T22:06:18.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-12-05T22:06:21.858184+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2021-12-05T22:06:23.175212+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
2021-12-05T22:06:23.175242+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-12-05T22:06:23.175242+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-12-05T22:06:23.175242+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-05T22:06:23.175243+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/index.js'
2021-12-05T22:06:23.175243+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
2021-12-05T22:06:23.175243+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
2021-12-05T22:06:23.175244+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
2021-12-05T22:06:23.175244+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
2021-12-05T22:06:23.175245+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-12-05T22:06:23.175245+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: []
2021-12-05T22:06:23.175245+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-12-05T22:06:23.482127+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-12-05T22:06:23.561604+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-12-05T22:06:28.304373+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=crypto-cb-app.herokuapp.com request_id=7fc07e15-106c-4618-8f4a-f893304ef4e6 fwd="173.3.65.202" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Package.json (scripts):

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "postinstall": "tsc && mv -i -v public dist/ && rm -v -rf src",
    "watch-node": "nodemon server/server.ts",
    "watch-ts": "tsc -w",
    "deploy": "git add . && git commit -m Heroku && git push heroku master",
    "clean": "rm dist/bundle.js",
    "build-dev": "webpack serve --hot --mode development",
    "build-prod": "webpack --mode production"
  },
```

Procfile:

```
web: node index.js
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": [
      "./src/**/*"
, "database"  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to your repo or could you provide info on how your file structure looks like and what your index.js file has in it?

Comment: https://github.com/swizzlestix09/showMeCrypto

Comment: The error message is saying it cant find an index.js file under the /app folder. My guess if this is following a build where I expect the typescript is compiled into javascript in the /dist folder? Otherwise if it's just a `start` command then maybe you need to run `ts-node index.tsx`?

Comment: I didnt have ts-node installed. In My ts config file I have my  outDir directed at my dist, however my dist only ever has bundle files (because im using webpack i think). I dont have an app folder either, so when heroku is compiling my files to deploy im guess that that's something heroku implements? I don't have it in my package json or anywhere else that there's an /app folder. I downloaded ts node and changed my start from 'node index.js' to 'ts-node index.js' and the errors are more or less the same.

Comment: **'ts-node index.tsx